# Python Theory About Equal Operator and Array Definition

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I stumbled upon a theoretical question about how python works, and it got me puzzled. I tried to understand exactly what happened but couldn't find the answer in google - I'm a beginner, so I don't even know the terminology to make the apropriate search.

On the following code, when calling the function it changes myList, while I only wanted to create a list2 which was a copy of list1 (myList).

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,(1,2),(3,4)]

def onlyTuples(list1):
    list2 = list1 # here is my question
    for index,e in enumerate(list2):
        if type(list2[index]) is not tuple:
            list2[index] = (list2[index],)
    return(list2)

print(myList)
create_new_list = onlyTuples(myList) # triggered by this call
print(myList)
```

It's all good if I change `list2 = list1` to `list2 = list(list1)` and myList won't be changed when calling the function, but why?

The same thing doesn't happen with something like this:

```
a = 6
b = a
b = 7
print(a)
```

Any light upon the question will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The line: ‘list2 = list1’ does not make a copy.

Comment: `list2 = list(list1)` creating a new list  and `list2 = list1` just assigning the `list1` reference to `list2`

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Yes, `x = y` **never makes a copy**. You should read that Ned Batchelder link, it should be illuminating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python lists are passed by reference, so when you pass list to a function you pass its address in the memory. list2 = list1 won't create a copy of the list, it will save in list2 the address saved in list1. so change of list2 will change list1, but the function in the class list doesn't save the address, it copy a sequence to a list

Comment: oh I see, but why would I ever use that instead of directly changing list1? thanks man

Comment: there is not really a reason to make clones of list that way but in general pass by reference to function is used to change the list in the function without cloning the list and return a new one

Comment: **Nothing is ever passed by reference in Python**. The *type* of the object **is irrelevant to the evaluation strategy**, which is neither call by reference nor call by value

Answer (score 0):

To make a copy of a list, use:

```
newList = myList.copy()
```